# Convert NetworkCredentials to a PSCredential?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, powershell, networkcredentials

Is it possible to convert NetworkCredentials (or a variant) to a PSCredential?

I want to transparently use the credentials of the current user, but don't want to prompt them.

Answer (score 3):

```
$cred = new-object PSCredential($nc.UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $nc.Password -AsPlainText -Force))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Management.Automation")
$dc = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$psc = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $dc.UserName, $dc.SecurePassword
```

That would do it, except that the default credentials are not set for the current application domain in which PowerShell is running.

At least this illustrates how you can create a `PSCredential` from a persisted username and password. The `SecureString` is always a bummer but I believe `NetworkCredential` offers a plaintext constructor you can use and a `SecureString` property to read from.